# change method code at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to my source code of my application at run time. submit code via a text box and display result

Comment: to build something like dotnetfiddle i guess

Comment: Take a look at [compiling at runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx(v=vs.110).aspx) for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My advise:

A code at run time cannot be editted!

Specially when you're running the code and a client is using the service. You can edit the code by yourself only. Client would be using `if else` block statements only.

You can edit the code, and add some if else blocks to it, so that each time the user loads the page; due to those if else blocks, the code seems to be change!

But you cannot let the user edit it. It is less secure!

#### You asked for it:

However, you can still let them edit the page, as this (since you mentioned `asp.net`)

```
// create some variables
var DataToWrite = /* suppose this as the main variable; having others in it */;
var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/folder/file.txt"); // find the file
File.WriteAllText(@dataFile, userData); // write the lines to the file
result = "Information saved."; // show the result if any..
```

You can try out other stuff too, learn them here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/files,-images,-and-media/working-with-files

Comment: i can talk about security if i want to test my code IIS server with web aplication

Comment: So, here is the code then brother! :) Use it..

Answer (score 0):

You can't change your existing code at runtime, but you do have access to the compiler, through [the CSharpCodeProvider class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). (Have a look at the examples in the linked MSDN article.) This allows you to pass in a string or file and compile it. After you compile your code into an assembly, you can load, invoke and run it using classes found in the `Reflection` namespace. In this way you could compile and run user-entered code as a separate library.

I apologize for not including a concrete example - this is not a trivial task, and any example would likely be quite involved. However, I did do something like this once several years ago and I can confirm it is possible.

Finally, if you're going to do this, **please consider the security of your environment!**

Allowing users to enter code which you will then compile and run can be incredibly dangerous, as the user could conceivably write code to do anything, for example delete data, expose database structures, manipulate user accounts, or modify the registry. Take great care with how this is application exposed and what libraries are made available.